# Import zlib on stm32 microcontroller giving error Type undefined reference to `gzclose'

Tags: c, stm32, zlib

I'm trying an example of compressing a file using zlib, on a stm32 microcontroller.

It's just giving med the compiler error

> Type undefined reference to `gzclose'

I have looked on similar problems including the solution here on stackoverflow. Where it needs to be linked to zlib.

How do I do this when I'm Atollic TrueSTUDIO?

Answer (score 1):

try add library to project ( project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Libraries)

Comment: I dont find anything that looks like a library file in the zlib source code folder.? Do you know where to find it?

Comment: you need to compile zlib source first to create a library.